# Thingworx: filter QueryImplementingThingsWithData

Tags: thingworx

I would like to use QueryImplementingThingsWithData.
I created service GetPRwithoutCCR with corresponding code inside:

```
var query = {
    filters: {
        type: "EQ",
        fieldName: "name", value: "AAA"
    }
};

result = query;
```

[image]

But I am proceeding get all implemented things without applying filter. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not trigger the "QueryImplementingThingsWithData" on Mashup Loaded. Trigger it using the ServiceInvokeCompleted event from "GetPRwithoutCCR". This way you make sure you have received the result from "GetPRwithoutCCR" and the query string is available.

Comment: I apologize if naive question: what do I trigger the "GetPRwithoutCCR" object?  Can I trigger that from Mashup Loaded event? (to be clear, I don't have a "GetPR..." - however I am using it as an example context)